# Performance wise String Matching

Tags: php, regex, string, string-matching, strpos

I've a generic DB query function that runs the following checks every time an SQL query is issued:

1. `if (preg_match('~^(?:UPDATE|DELETE)~i', $query) === 1)`
2. `if (preg_match('~^(?:UPDATE|DELETE)~iS', $query) === 1)`
3. `if ((stripos($query, 'UPDATE') === 0) || (stripos($query, 'DELETE') === 0))`

I know that a simple `strpos()` call is way faster than doing a `preg_match()`, however since I'm calling **`strIpos()` twice** I'm really not sure which one should perform better.

The `S` pattern modifier in the second option also brings some confusion in my head, from the manual:

> When a pattern is going to be used
>   several times, it is worth spending
>   more time analyzing it in order to
>   speed up the time taken for matching.
>   If this modifier is set, then this
>   extra analysis is performed. At
>   present, studying a pattern is useful
>   only for non-anchored patterns that do
>   not have a single fixed starting
>   character.

In this case speed is not critical (otherwise I wouldn't be using this generic query function) but, I still would like to make it run as fast as possible while maintaining it's simplicity.

**Which of the above options should I choose?**

---

**EDIT:** I've [run a simple benchmark](http://gist.github.com/270018) and still I can't decide which method works better.

Here are the results for **10,000 tries** (total time taken, in seconds):

```
Array
(
    [match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 0.0965
            [preg_match] => 0.2445
            [preg_match?] => 0.1227
            [preg_match?S] => 0.0863
        )

    [no-match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 0.1165
            [preg_match] => 0.0812
            [preg_match?] => 0.0809
            [preg_match?S] => 0.0829
        )
)
```

**100,000 tries**:

```
Array
(
    [match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 1.2049
            [preg_match] => 1.5079
            [preg_match?] => 1.5564
            [preg_match?S] => 1.5857
        )

    [no-match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 1.4833
            [preg_match] => 0.8853
            [preg_match?] => 0.8645
            [preg_match?S] => 0.8986
        )
)
```

**1,000,000 tries**:

```
Array
(
    [match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 9.4555
            [preg_match] => 8.7634
            [preg_match?] => 9.0834
            [preg_match?S] => 9.1629
        )

    [no-match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 13.4344
            [preg_match] => 9.6041
            [preg_match?] => 10.5849
            [preg_match?S] => 8.8814
        )
)
```

**10,000,000 tries**:

```
Array
(
    [match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 86.3218
            [preg_match] => 93.6755
            [preg_match?] => 92.0910
            [preg_match?S] => 105.4128
        )

    [no-match] => Array
        (
            [stripos] => 150.9792
            [preg_match] => 111.2088
            [preg_match?] => 100.7903
            [preg_match?S] => 88.1984
        )
)
```

As you can see the results vary a lot, this makes me wonder if this is the correct way to do a benchmark.

Comment: ....and how long does the the query take to run? This looks like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following regexes since they seem to be faster (on matched and non-matched text):

1. `if (preg_match('~^(?:INSERT|REPLACE)~i', $query) === 1)`
2. `else if (preg_match('~^(?:UPDATE|DELETE)~i', $query) === 1)`
3. `else if (preg_match('~^(?:SELECT|EXPLAIN)~i', $query) === 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't use any of those.  I can't be sure without benchmarking, but I think a `substr()` would be a faster option than `stripos`, as it wouldn't scan the whole string.  Assuming `UPDATE` and `DELETE` always occur at the start of a query, and even better, they're both exactly 6 characters long, so you could do it in a single `substr()`:

```
$queryPrefix = strtoupper(substr($query,0,6));
if ($queryPrefix == 'UPDATE' || $queryPrefix == 'DELETE') {
```

If you needed to, you could add a `trim()` on there for any prefixed whitespace, but it probably isn't necessary.

If you're doing nested or sub-queries with UPDATE and DELETE, then obviously the above method wouldn't work, and I'd go with the `stripos()` route.  If you can avoid regular expressions in favour of normal string functions, it will be faster and less complicated.

Comment: I also though of that (not sure if `substr()` + `strtoupper()` is faster than `stripos()` though) but there is one problem: I wouldn't be able to check `REPLACE` nor `EXPLAIN` type of queries since they both have 7 chars.

Comment: All those functions (substr(), trim(), strtoupper()) create a new string (including memory allocation). I'd avoid that if possible.